Remap `ctrl` + non-english letter doesn't work. I can remap `å`, but not `<C-å>`
Remap ctrl + non-english letter doesn't work. I can remap å, but not <C-å>.
-- this one works:
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<C-u>', ':vertical resize +5<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })

-- these one doesn't work: (why?)
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<C-å>', ':vertical resize +5<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<C-æ>', ':vertical resize +5<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<C-ø>', ':vertical resize +5<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })

-- suprisingly, these works:
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', 'å', ':vertical resize +5<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', 'æ', ':vertical resize +5<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', 'ø', ':vertical resize +5<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })

Can someone please make sense of this nonsense?
Is it possible to make ctrl + non-english letter work combo work in neovim?

Go into insert mode and press ctrl + q.
Then press the combination with the non-english letter (ctrl + å in my case).
Now you'll see what "neovim sees". In my case, I see ^[. Meaning, if I want to remap ctrl + å, I actually have to remap <C-[>.
The following works:
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<C-[>', ':vertical resize +5<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
Pressing ctrl + å will now execute :vertical resize +5<CR>
